# Sort by the three items in subarrays

Tags: ruby, algorithm, sorting

Given the following collection:

```
 collection = [
  ["Pennsylvania", "Bucks", "Doctor"], 
  ["New Jersey", "Essex", "Lawyer"], 
  ["New Jersey", "Essex", "Firefighter"],
  ["Florida", "Palm Beach", "Doctor"], 
  ["Florida", "Broward", "Doctor"],
  ["Florida", "Palm Beach", "Scientist"] 
]
```

I want to sort by first item ascending, second item ascending, and third item ascending. So the result would look like:

```
[
  ["Florida", "Broward", "Doctor"],
  ["Florida", "Palm Beach", "Doctor"], 
  ["Florida", "Palm Beach", "Scientist"],
  ["Pennsylvania", "Bucks", "Doctor"], 
  ["New Jersey", "Essex", "Firefighter"],
  ["New Jersey", "Essex", "Lawyer"], 
]
```

I can't seem to figure it out by using the sort_by iterator. I tried this:

```
collection.sort_by {|a,b| a <=> b }
 => [["Florida", "Palm Beach", "Doctor"], ["Florida", "Palm Beach", "Doctor"], ["New Jersey", "Essex", "Firefighter"], ["New Jersey", "Essex", "Lawyer"], ["Florida", "Broward", "Scientist"], ["Pennsylvania", "Bucks", "Doctor"]]
```

Clearly not the results I expected. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Each row in your collection consists of only 3 elements or it could be more ?

Comment: For this question, it will only be 3 as the title states. However, you do make a good point I did not think about when writing the qestion.

Comment: `collection.sort` returns what you want. (Note that "New Jersey" comes before "Pennsylvania".)

Comment: @Matt Or `collection.sort_by(&:itself)` if you're convinced you need to use `sort_by`.

Comment: Note the third paragraph of [Array#<=>](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E).

Comment: Could use block like, `collection.sort { |a,b| a.join <=> b.join }` but can you describe on which parameter you sorting out ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two tools here each of which can get the same result, but which have different consequences in terms of performance. `sort_by` has to transform each item *once and once only* in order to compare and sort. `sort` has to run that block for *each comparison* where there will be typically *N x log(N)* comparisons performed per sort operation. For large lists that can be significantly more operations than the number of entries in the array.

If you're doing an expensive transformation, `sort_by` is the winner here. For really dead-simple operations `sort` is sometimes better, but it's a subjective call.

For example, two approaches to the same result:

```
array = [ 7, 2, 5, 3, 4, 1, 6 ]

array.sort_by { |a| -a }
# => [7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

# Sort by negated values
array.sort { |a,b| -a <=> -b }
# => [7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

# Reverse the comparison, reverse the sort order
array.sort { |a,b| b <=> a }
```

All of these are valid approaches, but the advantage of the `sort_by` approach becomes more apparent when you minimize your code like this:

```
# Sort by unary minus (Integer#-@)
array.sort_by(&:-@)
```

Where in your specific case, say you wanted to sort in a case-insensitive manner:

```
collection = [
  ["NEW JERSEY", "Essex", "Lawyer"], 
  ["Florida", "Palm Beach", "Doctor"], 
  ["New Jersey", "ESSEX", "Firefighter"],
  ["Pennsylvania", "Bucks", "Doctor"], 
  ["florida", "Broward", "Doctor"],
  ["Florida", "Palm Beach", "Scientist"] 
]

s = collection.sort_by do |e|
  e.map(&:downcase)
end
# => [["florida", "Broward", "Doctor"], ["Florida", "Palm Beach", "Doctor"], ... ]
```

Calling `downcase` on an array is a somewhat expensive operation so you want to that as few times as possible to avoid creating a lot of duplicated objects that need to be garbage collected.

Answer (score 2):

You're using `Enumerable#sort_by` when you want to be using `Array#sort`.

`Enumerable#sort_by`

> Sorts enum using a set of keys generated by mapping the values in enum through the given block.

`Array#sort`

> The block must implement a comparison between a and b and return an integer less than 0 when b follows a, 0 when a and b are equivalent, or an integer greater than 0 when a follows b.

Comment: I am aware I was using Enumerable#sort_by. But why does the sort_by method not work in this case?

Comment: It shouldn't. `sort` takes arguments `|a,b|` while `sort_by` only takes one, you're expected to return the data you want to sort each item on.

Comment: @tadman is correct. I was trying to figure out a way you _could_ make `sort_by` work just to demonstrate, but couldn't really think of anything foolproof. Something like `collection.sort_by{ |ary| ary.map(&:chr).join }` gets close, but even that's only guaranteed to sort by the first character of each item in the nested array.